# Instalei o bower, gulp mas não sei qual arquivo editar

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, npm, bower

Comprei um tema da internet chamado [FUSE ANGULAR JS](http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/documentation/getting-started/introduction), na [documentação](http://withinpixels.com/themes/fuse/documentation/getting-started/introduction) dele, ele explica que eu devo instalar o npm, bower, gulp e etc... depois ele pede pra eu executar o seguinte comando `gulp serve`, e então alguma página do além é carregada no servidor com um header, sidebar e um `span` "Hello, I'm a sample page!"
o problema é que eu não sei onde está esse .html que ele carrega e muito menos o .css.

Basicamente, a estrutura do meu projeto está assim:
[image: Estrutura do meu projeto]

Alguém da uma help?
Obrigado!

Comment: Ah, jovem, você vai ter que procurar, é assim mesmo. Se você que tem o fonte em mãos não sabe, imagine nós, que só temos uma *screenshot* da estrutura do projeto. Um palpite pra você: olhe no arquivo de rotas, lá vai ter o que precisar.

Answer (score 1):

Dá uma olhada no index.html, lá procura pelo import de rotas ou algo do tipo, que nesse arquivo, você vai ver qual o nome do html que renderiza a página que você precisa.

PS: suspeito que você encontre o que procura nessa pasta *theming*